# why doesn't the result come out even though the code is successful

Tags: python, matplotlib

(Python matplotlib or seaborn)

I want output the result but the chart that shows the CPU usage over the week doesn't  come out

```
cpu_usage = [
[2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 12, 22, 23,
 45, 9, 33, 56, 23, 40, 21, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3], # Monday
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 7, 22, 45, 44,
 33, 9, 23, 19, 33, 56, 12, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2], # Tuesday
[2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5, 31,
 54, 7, 6, 34, 68, 34, 49, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3], # Wednesday
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 17, 24, 18,
 41, 3, 44, 42, 12, 36, 41, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4], # Thursday
[4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 12, 33, 27,
 43, 8, 38, 53, 29, 45, 39, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4], # Friday
[2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 8, 4, 2, 3,
 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3], # Saturday
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2,
 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 45, 26, 33, 2, 2, 1], # Sunday
]

labels=["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]

for day in range(len(cpu_usage)):
  plt.plot(np.arange(24),cpu_usage[day],"--o",label=labels[day],linewidth=.4,markersize=4)

plt.xticks(np.arange(24))
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.xlabel('hour')
plt.ylabel('cpu usage')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Unable to reproduce - the chart shows at the end

Comment: Add missing imports: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and
`import numpy as np`, the code is working for me too.

Comment: I've already try what you sugest but it doesn't  work the chart not show

Comment: This must be an issue with your environment. To debug, try first the code in Google Colab.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to wrap all your data into a dataframe, label it properly, and use pandas plotting

```
import pandas as pd
cpu_usage = [
[2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 12, 22, 23,
 45, 9, 33, 56, 23, 40, 21, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3], # Monday
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 7, 22, 45, 44,
 33, 9, 23, 19, 33, 56, 12, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2], # Tuesday
[2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5, 31,
 54, 7, 6, 34, 68, 34, 49, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3], # Wednesday
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 17, 24, 18,
 41, 3, 44, 42, 12, 36, 41, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4], # Thursday
[4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 12, 33, 27,
 43, 8, 38, 53, 29, 45, 39, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4], # Friday
[2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 8, 4, 2, 3,
 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3], # Saturday
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2,
 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 45, 26, 33, 2, 2, 1], # Sunday
]

labels=["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]

df = pd.DataFrame(cpu_usage).T # transpose to put days as columns
df.columns = labels

df.plot()
```

This gives you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Here is a one liner using both pandas and numpy.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(cpu_usage).T, columns=labels)
```

To plot the dataframe `df` use this:

```py
df.plot(kind="line")
```

[image]

### Multiple Subplots Stacked Vertically for Clarity

The plot we made earlier may not be good enough for clarity. Using multiple subplots, stacked vertically, sharing the same x-axis could offer greater clarity instead.

Here, we first scale the readings by the maximum value of all days (this ensures all the plots are expressed in a comparable scale. And then we plot the rescaled dataframe (`df_rescaled`) as area charts, with `subplots=True` and no `ylabel`.

```py
max_value = df.values.max()
df_rescaled = df / max_value
_ = df_rescaled.plot(
    kind="area", 
    xlabel="hour", 
    subplots=True, 
    stacked=False, 
    title=f"Daily CPU Usage (in hrs.): Scaled by {max_value:.2f} hrs.", 
    figsize=(10, 10)
)
```

[image]

### Dummy Data

```py
cpu_usage = [
[2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 12, 22, 23,
 45, 9, 33, 56, 23, 40, 21, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3], # Monday
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 7, 22, 45, 44,
 33, 9, 23, 19, 33, 56, 12, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2], # Tuesday
[2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 2, 5, 31,
 54, 7, 6, 34, 68, 34, 49, 6, 6, 2, 2, 3], # Wednesday
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 17, 24, 18,
 41, 3, 44, 42, 12, 36, 41, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4], # Thursday
[4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 12, 33, 27,
 43, 8, 38, 53, 29, 45, 39, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4], # Friday
[2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 2, 8, 4, 2, 3,
 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 2, 6, 1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 3], # Saturday
[1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2,
 2, 5, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 45, 26, 33, 2, 2, 1], # Sunday
]

labels=["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"]
```